# Finder and Virtual directories on OS X

Tags: macos, finder

I need to write an application like Dropbox, but where directories are "virtual". For example you can access files using file extensions or tags, or other things.

If i don't want to duplicate files (under the extensions and under the tags folders), is there a way to creare a "virtual file system"? Something like Fuse (but MacFuse is dead), and that i can use in a Bundle. Or a finder plugin?

Or can i write my own "finder" and import navigation panels (with ready-to-use file associations, etc.)?

Comment: There appears to be a replacement for MacFUSE called [Fuse4X](http://fuse4x.org/)